# Initiating a corda flow via interactive shell

Tags: corda

I am trying to initiate a flow from the shell, with this

```
flow start LoanIssueFlow$InitiatorFlow owner: "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB", supplier: "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB", bank: "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB", amount: Currencies.POUNDS(4), by: new Date(), penalty: 4, paid: Currencies.POUNDS(0)
```

And the flow constructor is as follow:

```
public InitiatorFlow(Party owner, Party supplier, Party bank, Amount<Currency> amount, Date by, double penalty, Amount<Currency> paid) {
        this.state = new LoanState(owner, supplier, bank, amount, by, penalty, paid);
    }
```

i am getting this error:

```
No matching constructor found:
- [net.corda.core.identity.Party, net.corda.core.identity.Party, net.corda.core.identity.Party, net.corda.core.contracts.Amount<java.util.Currency>, java.util.Date, double, net.corda.core.contracts.Amount<java.util.Currency>]: Could not parse as a command: Did not recognise the currency in Currencies.POUNDS(4) or could not parse
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

this is the right way of initiating that flow:

```
flow start LoanIssueFlow$InitiatorFlow owner: "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB", supplier: "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB", bank: "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB", amount: $100, by: 2020-01-01, penalty: 4, paid: $0
```